# Paypal donate button for my personal site

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, donations

I am using asp.net 3.5 and C#.

I have a pay pal account, I want to associate a Donate button to my Pay Pal account. I have checked pay pal site, under Merchant service > Website Payment Standards ... I am getting only three buttons [Buy Now, Add to Cart & Subscribe], but their is no "DONATE" button that I can use for my personal website.

Please help me how to add DONATE "Paypal" button to my website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside). The page lets you generate HTML-code for a donate button. Simply paste the generated code to your website where you want it.

Note that you will need a Premier or Business account at paypal.

Comment: I have created a personal account on Pay Pal, is their any way either I can upgrade my account to Premier or Business or create a donate button with existing account.

Please help

Comment: You can upgrade your current account to a premier account.

Go to "Sign up", click on the link "Already have a PayPal account? Upgrade now.", press "upgrade now", log in to your account and follow the instructions on screen.

Comment: @Undepth: cant we receive any fund in paypal personal account?